# Javascript replace - not working with string of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to create a sort of 'template' in plain old html, which can then have elements inserted by another javascript function.

So, I've got

```
var string = "<div id='<@nameInsert>' style='padding: 2px;'>here's some text and stuff</div>";
```

And in a function I'm trying to replace <@nameInsert> with the name I'm using...

```
string.replace("/<@nameInsert>", "525");
```

But, it don't work. Some sort of escaping thing, wrong idea this, or what?

Comment: Sure it doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/alfabravoteam/xLdQT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use quotes if you want to use regular expressions

```
string.replace(/<@nameInsert>/, "525");
```

But in your case you don't really need regular expressions. Just use a string:

```
string.replace("<@nameInsert>", "525");
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because you are trying to replace a string that doesn't exist in the other string.

I think that you are mixing two different ways of replacing. You can replace using a string:

```
string.replace("<@nameInsert>", "525");
```

and you can replace using a regular expression:

```
string.replace(/<@nameInsert>/, "525");
```

The part with slashes is a regular expression literal, which gives the same result as:

```
string.replace(new RegExp("<@nameInsert>"), "525");
```

You might prefer the regular expression, as you can then specify the global flag, which will make it replace every occurance, not just the first one:

```
string.replace(/<@nameInsert>/g, "525");
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa. One problem seems to be that this doesn't work for content within tags - for instance finding and replacing 'text' - doesn't work?

Comment: @waxical: The `replace` method doesn't care that the string happens to contain HTML code; text inside the tag is not handled differently. Note that the `replace` method doesn't change the string, it returns the new string. You have to use the return value: `string = string.replace(/text/g, 'woohaa!');`.

Comment: Thanks Guffa. I did eventually find that bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works ok like this,

```
string=string.replace("<@nameInsert>", "525");
```

here is an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript">

  function test(){
    var string = "<div id='<@nameInsert>' style='padding: 2px;'>here's some text and stuff</div>";
    string=string.replace("<@nameInsert>", "525");
    alert(string);
  }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="test" name="test" onclick="test()">  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you use slash (/) or quote (") for this since you only have one string to replace.. but just make sure you understand the replace method.. it won't replace the existing string, but rather return a modified copy of it.. 
so you can do it like this:

```
string = string.replace(/<@nameInsert>/, "525");
```